# Delete card from Tispr card stack

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I want to do a delete function with [Thispr Card](https://github.com/tispr/tispr-card-stack). Can you guide me how to do that. I did reloading the view after remove an object from the stack but it's crashing for me.

After I go to the next view and perform the delete action. then when come back my stack should be refreshed. In viewdidappear() I did this

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)



    if(dm.cardshouldRefresh || isFirsttimeLoad)
    {

        com.showProgress()

        self.getAuthorizations() { (status) in

            self.dm.cardshouldRefresh=false
            self.isFirsttimeLoad=false
            self.com.removeProgress()
            if (status)
            {
                self.setupCardView()

            }

        }
    }

    else
    {
        print(arrayAuthorization)

    }



}

func makecollectionViewEmpty()
{
    arrayAuthorization.removeAll()
    vwBtnPanelBottom.removeFromSuperview()
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

But this is crashing once I try to swipe after loading.
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below methods in `TisprCardStackExample` project and you will get remove method.

**TisprCardStackDemoViewController.swift**

```
//method to remove card
@IBAction func addNewCards(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    countOfCards -= 1
    if(countOfCards >= 0){
        cardWasRemoved()
    }
}
```

**TisprCardStackViewController.swift**

```
open func cardWasRemoved() {
    if layout.newCardShouldAppearOnTheBottom {
        layout.cardDidRemoved(0)
    } else {
        layout.cardDidRemoved(numberOfCards() - 1)
    }
}
```

**TisprCardStackViewLayout.swift**

```
func cardDidRemoved(_ newCardIndex:Int) {        
    collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] _ in
        self?.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: newCardIndex, section: 0)])
        }, completion: { _ in
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but a little clarification need. layout.cardDidRemoved(0) what is this 0? Do I need to pas the index of the car that I want to delete?